# Convert To Range - dynamically grab tablename

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I found the following post on this site.

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects("TableName").Unlist
```

Problem is that I get different tables and I don't know the tablename.  I know that A2 will always be a part of the table and I see the tablename on the sheet in excel.  Is there a way to grab the tablename and apply it dynamically in the code?

Answer (score 0):

Yes:

```
ActiveSheet.cells(2,1).ListObject.Name
```

Gives you the name of the table that Cell A2 is in. So:

```
ActiveSheet.ListObjects(ActiveSheet.cells(2,1).ListObject.Name).Unlist
```

Will do the job